# How to integrate $\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{4t-t^2}} \, dt$ using trig substitution.

Tags: calculus, integration, trigonometry

How do I integrate $\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{4t-t^2}} \,dt$? I solved this integral by a very long process(over 2 pages of work) and I got the answer of $6\sin^{-1}(\frac{t-2}{2})-\frac{t+6}{2}\sqrt{4t-t^2}+C$ and I want to know if there's a faster way of solving this problem. An example I saw solved by switching $4t-t^2$ into $4-(t-2)^2$ which made it much simpler, but I don't understand how they got that so my process was much more tedious. All help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They got that by completing the square for $t^2 -4t$

$$
t^2 -4t = (t-a)^2 + u
$$
$$
t^2 -4t = t^2 - 2at + a^2 + u
$$
$$ -2a = -4 \rightarrow a = 2$$
$$
t^2 -4t = (t-2)^2 -4
$$
$$
4t-t^2 = 4 - (t-2)^2
$$

Comment: So $u$ is always $-2a$ or is the $-2$ depending on the value of $a$? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

You have a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term: $4t-t^2$.

The standard method in algebra for reducing a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with a first-degree term to a problem involving a quadratic polynomial with no first-degree term is completing the square.

\begin{align}
4t-t^2 = -(t^2-4t)=4-(t^2-4t+4) & = 4-(t-2)^2 \\[8pt]
& = 4\left( 1-\left( \frac{t-2}{2} \right)^2 \right) \\[8pt]
& = 4(1-u^2).
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

First make the substitution $t=u+2$ so that the integral simplifies to,

$$\int\frac{t^2}{\sqrt{4t-t^2}}\mathrm{d}t=\int\frac{(u+2)^2}{\sqrt{4-u^2}}\mathrm{d}u.$$

The appropriate trig substitution is now much more transparent.